# copy several mysql rows based on foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I want to copy several rows in a mysql table based on a foreign key, and asign the new rows a new foreign key ID.  Assuming my table layout looks like this:

`test`
`-----`
`table1_id int(11)`
`value varchar(20)`

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the query would need to look like this:
`INSERT INTO test (table1_id, value) (SELECT '2', value FROM test WHERE table1_id=1)`

which would copy all rows with the foreign key ID '1' and assign the new rows with ID 2 instead.  If the table contains more rows you could add them or change order in the SELECT part, like this

 `...(SELECT row1, '{$new_id}', value, another_row FROM...`